# Submitting some snapshots of nature from my collection as Ubuntu backgrounds

Tags: desktop-background, community

I want to submit some of snapshots of nature taken by me to Ubuntu so that other Ubuntu users can use them as background pictures. May I do so? What's the procedure?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is usually a wallpaper contest sometime in the release cycle. Keep an eye on the Ubuntu related news outlets. As an example, here is the announcement for 12.04: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/01/ubuntu-12-04-wallpaper-contest-launched